# Micronaut: Make files inside resources publicly available

Tags: java, micronaut

I have a small micronaut application where I need to serve files inside `resources`. Those files should be publicly accessible, so if I enter the url for that file, it would open directly in the browser (they are small images).

I tried using

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: myapp
  router.static-resources:
    enabled: true
    paths: classpath:data
    mapping: "/**"
```

but the response is always the same:

```json
{
  "message": "Page Not Found",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/data/per.svg",
      "templated": false
    }
  }
}
```

What additional configuration do I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues in your configuration:

1. You have `micronaut.router.static-resources.enabled` but it should be `micronaut.router.static-resources.default.enabled`. So the `default` is missing.
2. You are mapping your static resources stored in the *data* directory in the class path to root */* web path. So you can access that *per.svg* file on *http://localhost:8080/per.svg*.

But it is better to use separate context then root to prevent conflict with controller paths. So, you can map it to *static* for example:

```yaml
micronaut:
  application:
    name: myapp
  router:
    static-resources:
      default:
        enabled: true
        mapping: "/static/**"
        paths: classpath:data
```

Then you can access it on *http://localhost:8080/static/per.svg*

Comment: I get the error: `Message: Unrecognizable resource path: "classpath:data"` even though inside my JAR there definitely is the data directory containing the static files.